# R Extract columns in list of dataframes into lists

Tags: r, list, loops, dataframe

I have a very specific problem. I have a list of dataframes:

```
AB_df = data.frame(replicate(2,sample(0:130,201,rep=TRUE)))
BC_df = data.frame(replicate(2,sample(0:130,200,rep=TRUE)))
DE_df = data.frame(replicate(2,sample(0:130,197,rep=TRUE)))
FG_df = data.frame(replicate(2,sample(0:130,203,rep=TRUE)))
AB_pc = data.frame(replicate(2,sample(0:130,201,rep=TRUE)))
BC_pc = data.frame(replicate(2,sample(0:130,200,rep=TRUE)))
DE_pc = data.frame(replicate(2,sample(0:130,197,rep=TRUE)))
FG_pc = data.frame(replicate(2,sample(0:130,203,rep=TRUE)))

df_list = list(AB_df, BC_df, DE_df, FG_df, AB_pc, BC_pc, DE_pc, FG_pc)
names(df_list) = c("AB_df", "BC_df", "DE_df", "FG_df", "AB_pc", "BC_pc", "DE_pc", "FG_pc")
```

I want to extract now the 1st column of every 2nd dataframe into a list called "picked" and the other dataframes into a list called "unpicked". I tried doing this with a loop and sequences. The sequences are giving me the correct list entries, but in my output lists I always only get the same entry. This is my try so far:

```
picked = list()
unpicked = list()

for (a in 1:(length(df_list)/2)) {
  for (b in seq(1,length(df_list), by = 2)){
    for (c in seq(2,length(df_list), by = 2)) {
      picked[[a]] = df_list[[b]][[1]]
      unpicked[[a]] = df_list[[c]][[1]]}}}
```

I think I am close, but something is still not right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `lapply` to select 1st column of every second dataframe (`picked`) and select the remaining dataframe in `unpicked`.

```
picked <- lapply(df_list[c(FALSE, TRUE)], `[`, 1)
unpicked <- lapply(df_list[c(TRUE, FALSE)], `[`, 1)
```

We use `FALSE`/`TRUE` to select alternate list elements. So here we select element 2, 4, 6 and 8 and with `[` subset 1st columns from the data. For `unpicked` we select list element 1, 3, 5 and 7 and get their first column.

Comment: Thanks, can you please explain me what , `[`, 1) does?

Comment: @Mr.Spock I aded some explanation. For `unpicked` do you want 1st column as well? or the complete dataframe?

Comment: for unpicked also the first column. Thank you, I understand it now!

Answer (score 0):

we can `split` to get a `list` of picked and unpicked

```
lst1 <- lapply(split(seq_along(df_list), seq_along(df_list) %%2), 
          function(i) df_list[i][1])
```